# Cors domain problem with <iframe> and .htaccess, why?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, .htaccess

My problem is my iframe blocks my Javascript access, when I try to access to the content inside the `<iframe>` of my subdomain(test.example.com:xx), xx is the line number of my code, look below the error.

Error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at
>   window.onload (https://example.com)

Here the code of https://example.com/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <iframe id="frames" src="https://test.example.com">
    </iframe>
<script>

var x = document.getElementById("frames");
console.log(x);
window.onload = function() {
    console.log(window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the code of my https://test.example.com/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>This is my test subdomain...<p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here the code of my .htaccess file, of both domains, my https://example.com and https://test.example.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Header always set x-frame-options "ALLOWALL"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type"
Header always set Origin: "*"
```

What went wrong and how can I fix it?

**Note**: I'm using Chrome, Firefox and Safari, to test my sites, The error is produced in this line:

```
console.log(window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: You cannot access`iFrame` data (html) cross origin ..  This is expected and **intentional**  --  Otherwise what's to stop you from posting an `iFrame` of a bank login and collecting the user info?

Comment: Zak, How i will allow my clients access to my subdomain using <iframe>?

Comment: Zak, I need share my contents openly!, without restrictions, is this a problem of browsers and not about the authorization of my .htaccess, maybe?

Comment: Zak, Why create the <iframe> tag, If it cannot be used for the initial essence(share the content of other site)?

Comment: Zak reply of your question..., What's to stop you from posting an iFrame of a bank login and collecting the user info?, the answer is simply, blocking using of iframe using .htaccess to all domains except the domain of bank, but the situation here is: 1. My site is not a bank!, 2. Im the owner of my site.

Comment: Zak, And what about the sites who want allow cors access feature on his site?, they cannot use cors of his domains when they are the owners?, i really can't understand and i think your comment is out of topic.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Kimo41, i already read your comments, and i'm accord with you, the cors policy have to be decision of the owner of the website and domain, not of the web browsers, I think i have a good solution for you, you can try JS WORKERS, for allow cors in your domains if you are using Cloudflare as DNS.

Response headers:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  let response = await fetch(request)

  // Make the headers mutable by re-constructing the Response.
  response = new Response(response.body, response)
  response.headers.set('x-my-header', 'custom value')

  return response
}
```

Request Headers:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  // Make the headers mutable by re-constructing the Request.
  request = new Request(request)
  request.headers.set('x-my-header', 'custom value')

  return await fetch(request)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm in a enterprise plan of cloudflare, it works, finally someone give me a good solution...